# Upload .war file to Google app engine (GAE) using appcfg

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Out of curiosity, Is it possible to upload single .war file generated by maven to Google app engine using the tool appcfg.(/cmd/sh)?

I tried but got errors, when I specify the exploded directory (directory that contains gwt files) as the path, it worked.

Would be nice to specify single archive (.war) for upload as path to appcfg tool.

Please let me know if you have been able to do this or whether it's even supported.

Cheers
PB

Answer (score 1):

The Google App Engine makes no provision for uploading a single `.war` file.

Since a `war/` folder necessarily precedes the creation of a `.war` archive (since a `.war` archive is simply a zipped up `war/` directory) obtaining the `war/`directory is provably easier than obtaining a `.war` file.

Perhaps you are used to tomcat where you can just deploy a `.war` file through the admin interface. When tomcat receives that file, all it does is extract it under `webapps/`. I suspect that GAE fiddles with the contents of your `war/` a bit before it is actually uploaded to them anyway. If you provide more information about why you want to do this, perhaps we can discover the source of your confusion.

Comment: Thanks @Travis Webb for your input. Usually I like to manage my apps with maven. And at the same time, I do not want to go through convoluted steps before uploading my app to GAE. Since mvn generates a `.war` file, I was hoping I could just upload the `.war` to GAE using `appcfg` tool. I guess I will have to upload the directory that contains unarchived version of my project under `/target/` dir. Thanks

Comment: If you use maven you should not be using `appcfg` at all, you should use `maven-gae-plugin`. Then you invoke `mvn package gae:deploy` and you're done. http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/

Comment: oh. didn't know of `maven-gae-plugin`. Thanks, will check it out..Cheers

Comment: For me the point is the upload latency. I'm working with GAE-Java. From Switzerland, it takes me about 10 minutes to upload 15 'files' (about 250Kb of data, and my internet connection provides me 1.8 Mb/s upload rate - it's not the issue). I managed to have all server-side classes packaged in a jar and that way I could reduce drastically the upload time (and also the instance loading time), but this technique is not available for the GWT files. And there is plenty of files... Do U see what I mean ? The war archive would provide a much faster upload.